# Iterate over array running async task on each element

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, asynchronous

I have a list of items, which I want to run an async task on each.

I want to synchronize so each element will be processed once the preceding element has completed. What I've tried so far is:

```
function processItems(items) {
    var i = 0;
    while(i < items.length) {
      asyncFunc(items[i], function() { i++ }); // asyncFunc takes a callback parameter       
    }
}
```

However this loops forever (I believe `i` is out of scope in the callback function).

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
function processItems(items) {
    var i = 0,
        length = items.length,
        fn = function() {
            if(i < length) {
                asyncFunc(items[i], fn);
                i++;
            }
        };

    fn();
}
```

`fn` is a function that sets the callback equal to itself as long as the index is less than the length. Then I call `fn` once to start it off. Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/8A8CG/

---

Alternatively, if `asyncFunc` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to process the items in a series:

```
function processItems(items) {
  return items.reduce((promise, item) => {
    return promise.then(() => asyncFunc(item));
  }, Promise.resolve());
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat, nice example of solving with recursion being simpler than an iterative method

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute a set of async function in series, I highly recommend the [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) for node. 

<strike>It offers a [series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) method to execute async tasks in series. It also offers a [waterfall](https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfalltasks-callback) method that will pass the results of the previous task to the next task.</strike>

Oops. You are looking for [eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachseriesarr-iterator-callback). Here's how it might work for you:

```
var async = require('async');

async.eachSeries(items, asyncFunc, function(err){ if(err) return "OH NO"; return "Yay!"})
```

Make sure `asyncFunc` invokes a callback with either an error or null.

Comment: Looking at the series example, how would this translate to my problem of iterating over the array and calling an async on each one in succession?

Comment: @ioseph I modified my answer to the demonstrate the appropriate use of the async library.