# Creating async functions for an array loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous

I have never (intentionaly!) worked with async functions in javascript.
I have to do an assignment that requires I use async functions for elements of an array (ie `for(let i=0;i<array.length;i++){do_Something_Async_here()}` ) to proccess them in PARALLEL.

I have tried using setTimeout like this

```
unique.forEach(function (number, index)
   {
       setTimeout( populateResults(index,number), 0 );
   });
function populateResults(index,number)
{
   alert("populating results: index:"+index+" number:"+number);
   var jp;
   for(var i=0;i<1000000;i++)
   {
       jp=Math.pow(2,100);
   }
   alert("results populated: index:"+index+" number:"+number);
   return jp;
}
```

and like this

```
let promises = [];
for (var i=0;i<unique.length;i++) {
    promises.push(populateResults(i,unique[i]));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function(results){
   console.log(results);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

I actually do something with the number and index, but I've simplified it here.
Now, when I run the code, in both cases, it seems like i normally execute code in C or java. Sequentially. What am i missing? How to make them run in parallel?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `populateResults` isn't an async function, it's just an ordinary function so it will execute completely before you even push it into `promises` which despite its name doesn't contain any promises. Try again with an actual async function that returns a `Promise` and you may see a different result.

Comment: Did you try closure? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8n00zre7/

Comment: Look at SimpleJ's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924038/iterate-over-array-running-async-task-on-each-element He uses `setTimeout()`

Comment: @Duncan i havent used Promises before. How do I do that? to. And how do I create an async function? do i need node.js or something else? Can i do it using plain javascript? Because ` var jdsd=async function fub(c){};` shows me a missing semicolon error.

Comment: `Promise.all` already resolves ALL the promises asyncronously in a parallel way, it just **returns whenever all the promises are done**, but it actually do perform all the elements in a parallel way. What are you exactly not getting from your code? do you want a callback for each promise executed and want to execute all the promises in parallel?

Comment: @AakashVerma As i understand it, in simpleJ's answer, it exetutes a copy of the function fn every second? (execute the nth copy aften n seconds)
If instead of the console.log() there, it was something that required a lot of time (more than 1 sec), would the second copy start before the first one ends? 
Also i tried the fiddle in simpleJ, but it doesnt seem to do anything when i change console.log with something else. Is it my problem? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/nfo4j8cr/)

Comment: @briosheje that is exactly what i want to do. But the functions execute sequentially.

Comment: Alright ,my bad. That function fooled me like anything. Obviously, that is for processing async functions one after the other or serially (only after the previous one finishes). What you need is a bunch of functions executing in an async or independent fashion. What say about 'async' package?

Comment: @KristjanKica : **no**, the functions are running in a parallel way, it's just that you **can't see that** because you are calling the result just once. https://jsfiddle.net/8ybzu0pz/ here is an example that may give you a clearer idea of what is happening: all the promises are being started in a **parallel** way. I'm handling a generic for each callback which proves that they all are executed in a parallel way. If you want them to be executed **sequentially** and make one to start after each other, then that's another situation. It may be helpful to understand exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An async function in Javascript is one that immediately returns a `Promise` and at some future point completes running.

Unlike C or Java, Javascript is only single threaded, so don't mistake an async function for one that runs in a separate thread: all of the code runs in the same thread, so completely sequentially. All you can do in an async javascript function is delay doing the work until some time later.

That means async functions are useful for code that fetches some remote data, or has a timeout, or waits for an event from the user before continuing.

You could simulate an asynchronous function here by using `setTimeout`:

```
function delayedPopulateResults(index, number) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function() { resolve(populateResults(index, number); },
            Math.random());
    });
}
```

Now if you call `delayedPopulateResults` instead of `populateResults` your second block of code will create all the promises and log the results when completed. But remember all that does is introduce a random delay before the code executes: so the calls to `populateResults()` will execute in random order, but still each one has to complete before the next one runs.

If you can use the latest versions of Ecmascript (ES7) then you can use the `async` and `await` keywords to simplify this, but to run the code in your browser you probably need to use a transpiler such as Babel or Typescript to render the code in ES5.